# Randomized quicksort partitioning probability

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm reading [Algorithms Illuminated: Part 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075YQP38X), and problem 5.2 states:

> Let ɑ be some constant, independent of the input array length n,
>   strictly between 0 and 1/2. What is the probability that, with a
>   randomly chosen pivot element, the Partition subroutine produces a
>   split in which the size of both the resulting subproblems is at least
>   ɑ times the size of the original array?

Answer choices are:

> 1. ɑ
> 2. 1 - ɑ
> 3. 1 - 2ɑ
> 4. 2 - 2ɑ

I'm not sure how to answer this question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let there be `N` elements in the array. If the picked pivot is one of the smallest `[Nα]` elements in the array, then the left partition's size will be less than `Nα`. Similarly, if the picked pivot is one of the largest `[Nα]` elements in the array, the right partition's size will be less than `Nα`.

Hence, there are `N - 2 * [Nα]` elements that you can pick such that both partitions have size greater than or equal to `Nα`. Since the algorithm picks a pivot randomly, all elements have an equal probability of getting picked.

So, the probability of getting such a split is `1 - 2α + O(1 / N)`.

Comment: By "pick one of the smallest Nα elements", do you mean pick that element as the pivot? Since α is not an integer, `Nα` may be a fraction. Can you pick the 3.5 smallest element from an array?
Please elaborate in your answer, don't respond in comments.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar You can truncate the fractional value. The difference is negligible. I have updated the answer with the same.

Comment: I think you mean the probability is `1 - 2α`. Your answer `1 - 2α + O(1 / N)` is not one of the choices, and doesn't follow from your argument. `(N - 2 * Na)/N = 1 - 2a`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar That's what I meant by negligible. Some fractional part over N will be left because you can't pick 3.5 elements.