# Randomized quicksort recursion depth

Tags: algorithm, recursion, quicksort

I'm reading [Algorithms Illuminated: Part 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075YQP38X), and problem 5.3 states:

> Let ⍺ be some constant, independent of the input array length n,
>   strictly between 0 and 1/2. Assume you achieve the approximately
>   balanced splits from the [preceding
>   problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53312485/839733) in every
>   recursive call - so whenever a recursive call is given an array of
>   length k, each of its two recursive calls is passed a subarray with
>   length between ⍺k and (1 - ⍺)k. How many successive recursive calls
>   can occur before triggering the base case? Equivalently, which levels
>   of the algorithm’s recursion tree can contain leaves? Express your
>   answer as a range of possible numbers d, from the minimum to the
>   maximum number of recursive calls that might be needed. [Hint: The
>   formula that relates logarithmic functions with different bases is log
>   n = ln n]

Answer choices:

> 1. -log(n)/log(⍺) <= d <= -log(n)/log(1 - ⍺)
> 2. 0 <= d <= -log(n)/log(⍺)
> 3. -log(n)/log(1 - ⍺) <= d <= -log(n)/log(⍺)
> 4. -log(n)/log(1 - 2⍺) <= d <= -log(n)/log(1 - ⍺)

My analysis:

If ⍺ < 1/2, then 1 - ⍺ > ⍺, thus the branch with subarray length (1 - ⍺)n will have greater recursion depth.

```
n / (1 - ⍺)^d = 1
Taking log[base(1 - ⍺)] on both sides
log[base(1 - ⍺)](n) = d
By log rule
d = log(n)/log(1 - ⍺)
```

The best case should be `log(n)/log(⍺)`, thus answer 1 seems to be correct. However, I'm confused by the minus signs; I don't understand how can the height of a recursion tree be negative. Also, I'd like someone to validate my analysis as shown above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis has a small bug.

The correct equation will be `n * (1 - ⍺) ^ d = 1` rather than `n / (1 - ⍺) ^ d = 1`.
This adds the negative sign you are looking for.

Remember that both `⍺` and `(1 - ⍺)` are less than 1. So, there logarithms are negative. Adding one more negative symbol on that results in an overall positive value for minimum and maximum depth.

Comment: Why  n * (1 - ⍺) ^ d = 1?

Comment: @ParvizPirizade At each level of recursion, an array of size k is split into ⍺k and (1-⍺)k. For recursion to end, the size has to reach base case 1. so n * (1-⍺) * (1-⍺)..d times = 1